# Google Cloud Artifact Registry - How can we install published python package from artifact registry of one project to another within an org

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-iam, install.packages, google-artifact-registry

I am unable to install python package published in Artifact Registry of one project to another project jupyter instance within same organization. I am getting **ERROR: No matching distribution found **

Below is the command I am using to install the pkg:
pip install --upgrade 
--index-url=https://**REGION**-python.pkg.dev/**PROJECT_ID**/**REPOSITORY_ID**/simple/ 
**PACKAGE_NAME**==**VERSION**

I have already verified the URL, permission and version.
Same command is running fine when I install the pkg in same project, however getting the error while installing it on different project.

I have ensured that I have necessary permissions and access to the Artifact Registry and the package within the projects. The service account that I am using have the artifact registry read permissions on source project and editor permissions on target project.

Please suggest any way to install the pkg published in artifact registry of different project if we have the necessary permissions.